# My user cannot access DNS but I can. Why?

Tags: networking, dns

```
C:\Users\dian>ping google.com -t
^C
C:\Users\dian>ping 1.1.1.1

Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=59
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=59
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=59
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=59

Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 16ms, Average = 16ms

C:\Users\dian>ping google.com -t
^C
C:\Users\dian>
```

So I know DNS must be the issue. Ping 1.1.1.1 works fine. Ping google.com -t doesn't work.

I used simple DNScrypt

```
C:\Users\dian>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : jim-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : This Qualcomm Atheros network Controller connects you to the network.
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 10-78-D2-3B-5D-B6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-NordVPN Windows Adapter V9
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-FF-D2-E6-78-16
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Npcap Loopback Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Npcap Loopback Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-00-4C-4F-4F-50
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7555:fda9:cffa:5fac%9(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.95.172(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 687997004
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-C7-19-B8-10-78-D2-3B-5D-B6
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1E-BF-CE-84-1E-7A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-BF-CE-84-1E-7A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek 8811CU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-BF-CE-84-1E-7A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9d8e:508b:c185:9927%22(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.134(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, April 04, 2020 6:36:01 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, April 11, 2020 9:25:29 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 1092403150
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-C7-19-B8-10-78-D2-3B-5D-B6
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 14:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #13
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1A-7D-DA-71-13
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

What exactly was wrong?

My ISP, Biznet block DNS port. However, things work just fine in administrator account if I use simpleDnscrypt. That's how I can post here.

But Dian cannot.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Dian's PC has no DNS server assigned on the Wifi interface. It's pointing to 127.0.0.1 which is Dian's own PC. Unless he is running a DNS service on his laptop, that's the problem.

Either the DHCP server (wireless router) is giving out the wrong DHCP Option 8 (set to 127.0.0.1), OR Dian has overrided the DNS setting and specified 127.0.0.1 manually.

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek 8811CU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-BF-CE-84-1E-7A
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9d8e:508b:c185:9927%22(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.134(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, April 04, 2020 6:36:01 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, April 11, 2020 9:25:29 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 1092403150
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-C7-19-B8-10-78-D2-3B-5D-B6
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

To fix this, either update the DHCP or Wireless device and specify a valid DNS server (1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, or some ISP DNS).

OR have Dian manually update his Wireless interface and override the DNS to use a valid DNS service (1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, or some ISP DNS).

Good luck!